# Alter column type to enum with mapping

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I have a nullable boolean column `my_column`.

I have enum type called `my_enum` with 3 values (ENABLED/DISABLED/INHERITED).

I want to change this column data as follows:

- `TRUE` becomes `ENABLED`
- `FALSE` becomes `DISABLED`
- `NULL` becomes `INHERITED`

Is there a way to provide the mapping in a single alter table statement?

Schematically I'd want something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE my_type USING (
    {
      TRUE => ENABLED,
      FALSE => DISABLED,
      NULL => INHERITED
    }
  );
```

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression, with appropriate casting:

```
alter table my_table
    alter column my_column set data type my_type using (
        case my_column 
            when true  then 'enabled'::my_type
            when false then 'disabled'::my_type
            else            'inherited'::my_type
        end
    )
;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e64e597df2e2b8d13ef65593cc2cfb47)**:

Initial content of the table:

```
id | my_column
-: | :--------
 1 | t        
 2 | f        
 3 | null
```

After executing the `alter table` statement:

```
id | my_column
-: | :--------
 1 | enabled  
 2 | disabled 
 3 | inherited
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't notice your answer while was writing my own based on the comment to the question, I'm upvoting for help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is apparently pretty simple (thanks to @Bergi):

```
      ALTER TABLE my_table
        ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE my_type USING (
          CASE my_column
          WHEN TRUE  THEN 'ENABLED'::my_type
          WHEN FALSE THEN 'DISABLED'::my_type
          ELSE            'INHERITED'::my_type
          END
        );
```

Comment: Worked for PostgreSQL